# keras won't allow me to add layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to make a neural network using keras and everytime I try to add a layer I get a list of errors relating to the call the way I'm calling it is `model.add(Dense(768,input_dim=3072,init='uniform',activation='relu'))`
and the errors I get are the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nn2.py", line 52, in <module>
    model.add(Dense(768,input_dim=3072,init='uniform',activation='relu'))
  File "/Users/lens/Documents/NNproject/neuralenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py", line 1132, in __init__
    activity_regularizer=regularizers.get(activity_regularizer), **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lens/Documents/NNproject/neuralenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 456, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lens/Documents/NNproject/neuralenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 294, in __init__
    generic_utils.validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs)
  File "/Users/lens/Documents/NNproject/neuralenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 792, in validate_kwargs
    raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'init')
```

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a single `init` argument for keras Dense layers. You'll need to specify the initialization for `kernel_initializer` and `bias_initializer` separately.